# What does the dedupe parameter do in the Nominatim Search API?

Tags: nominatim

It seem like it's doing more than just removing duplicates but I can't find any good documentation on it.  The [API docs](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Parameters) currently just say:

> dedupe=[0|1]
>
> No explanation yet.

I'm running my own Nominatim that's been forked from the original a few months ago and I use the public Nominatim as a back up when mine doesn't respond.  So I am interested in answers regarding the latest  public Nominatim.  On my own Nominatim, I haven't noticed duplicates in results.

I have noticed differences when setting `dedupe` to `0` or `1`.  [Here's a diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/vax5f71m) where you can see that even with `dedupe=0`, there are no duplicates yet with `dedupe=1`, the results are different.  BTW `dedupe=1` seem to match the default with no `dedupe` set.

Maybe Nominatim is removing duplicates based on GPS and boundaries and not just `place_id`'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could check the source code in [here](https://git.openstreetmap.org/nominatim.git/). Basically, the `dedupe` parameter is used to check whether there is a duplicate on the search result or not. it will be used when generating the query to get the data from the database.

the parameters which are used when trying to check for duplication are place_id and the address (the country code, postcode, address, etc). you could check the sql function in [here](https://git.openstreetmap.org/nominatim.git/blob/9a2c0f23a66130fa221a32d852a71ca985f0e36c:/sql/functions.sql) (the function is called `get_address_by_language`)

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of the `dedupe` parameter but found your question while searching for `nominatim duplicate addresses`.

I'm having an issue with some buildings existing twice in the Nominatim data with slightly different variants of the address (e.g. Avenue vs Boulevard suffix, front door vs back door as coordinates).